# Printing char arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

If I print out a char array normally

```
char[] c = new char[]{'3','b','o'};
System.out.println(c); //prints 3bo
```

the output is a string. However, if I concatenate a String it prints the array memory location.

```
System.out.println("" + c); //prints [C@659e0bfd
```

I would have expected it to print as a String and I'm sure why this behavior happens. Any explanations?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Solution is to use [`new String(c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#String%28char%5B%5D%29):

```
System.out.println("" + new String(c));
```

And the `"" +` is really bogus and should be removed.

Below is why you get what you get.

---

`System.out` is a [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html). `println()` has an overload for [`println(char[] x)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28char%5B%5D%29):

> **Prints an array of characters** and then terminate the line. This method behaves as though it invokes `print(char[])` and then `println()`.

---

`"" + c` is *string concatenation*, which is defined in [JLS 15.18.1 String Concatenation Operator `+`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1):

> If only one operand expression is of type `String`, then string conversion ([§5.1.11](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11)) is performed on the other operand to produce a string at run time.

And [JLS 5.1.11 String Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.11) says:

> [...] the conversion is performed as if by an **invocation of the toString method** of the referenced object with no arguments [...]

**`toString()` is not defined for arrays**, so the [`Object.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) method is invoked:

> The `toString` method for class `Object` returns a string consisting of the **name of the class** of which the object is an instance, the **at-sign** character '`@`', and the unsigned hexadecimal representation of the **hash code** of the object. In other words, this method returns a string equal to the value of:
>
> ```
>  getClass().getName() + '@' + Integer.toHexString(hashCode())
> ```

Which is why you get something like `[C@659e0bfd` when you do string concatenation.

Comment: Note when converting from a char array to String it's sufficient to do `String my_string = new String(char_array);` (i.e. without the "" + in front)

Comment: @RobHoff What do you think this statement in the answer means? *"And the `"" +` is really bogus and should be removed."*

Answer (score 1):

When you call System.out.println(char []array) the PrintStream class writes the chars (one of its overloads handles the job).

But for the second case, java converts the char array to string by calling its toString method which is a regular array toString method. And concatenating it with empty string, you receive the array signature [C*.... This is an expected and normal behavior.

**Edit** 
Here is the PrintStream code that gets eventually called when you call 'System.out.println(c)':

```
 private void write(char buf[]) {
    try {
        synchronized (this) {
            ensureOpen();
            textOut.write(buf);
            textOut.flushBuffer();
            charOut.flushBuffer();
            if (autoFlush) {
                for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++)
                    if (buf[i] == '\n')
                        out.flush();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (InterruptedIOException x) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
    catch (IOException x) {
        trouble = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest form is:

```
Arrays.toString(c);
```

and if it is a 2D array, then use [`Arrays.deepToString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) as follows:

```
Arrays.deepToString(twoDArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, you have an instance in a print stream. In the second case, you have the array concatenated with a string. If you did something like

```
System.out.println("" + c[0]); // or whatever number you put in there
```

It would print some of the string you are looking for.

```
String stringfromArray = "" + new String(c);
```

,would function more like what you are looking for in the second part of your question, but you don't need to do the `"" +` part.

Comment: `new String(c)` would be a heck of a lot faster than looping `String = String + String`, which is about the worst way ever to incrementally build a string.

Answer (score 0):

One call is `PrintStream.println(char[])` the other call is `PrintStream.println(String)`.

This is because the JVM first evaluates `"" + c`.  This is done by evaluating `"" + c.toString()` which is identically to `c.toString()`.

So, your calls are equivalent to:

```
System.out.println(c);
System.out.println(c.toString());
```

And these two calls are different.

Answer (score 0):

the array of char can directly output,because it will insist on outputing untill the value is **null**
And the array of char **cannot use the way of toString()**,because it will only get the memory location,**so you can new String(the array of char)**

Answer (score 0):

**All of the above are great solutions and explanations. However, there is also another way to 'bypass' this problem:**

You can use two print statements, more specifically,

```
System.out.print("");
System.out.print(c);
```

This way they will be on the same line (b/c print does not use line feed to go to the next line) and you will not have to deal with any complications because of String concatenations.

For more information, see the  [Print Stream Documentation by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28char[]%29) .
Here is the documentation portion for print when a char[] is passed as the argument:

> public void print(char[] s)
>
> Prints an array of characters. The characters are converted into bytes according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the write(int) method.